# Does SharePoint support Excel spreadsheets linked to each other?

Tags: excel

Is it possible with Office 2007 + SharePoint 2007 to have a spreadsheet uploaded to a SharePoint document library having dependencies/links to other spreadsheets also stored in SharePoint? Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Actually I'm pretty sure that this is not supported according to http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101054571033.aspx specifically under the 'Unsupported Features' section that lists 'External references to linked workbooks'.

Comment: The URL doesn't resolve for me. I am finding the page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms496823(office.12).aspx. However, as noted by Brian Hayes, this page is referring to Excel Services which is different.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but I believe it is easier to move the data to Sharepoint and handle it in there. You can still use Excel for charts and pivot table stuff, but use Sharepoint to store the data.

Comment: +1. This could be a better option. The killer of course would be if there is extensive logic in the cells. It's worth noting though, that some auditors regard data in Excel as unreliable as it's too easily edited and difficult / impossible to trace to a source.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted Michal, is to Excel Services which would display it as a web based data format. I believe he is using SharePoint to store the document, and access another Excel doc in SharePoint. So I don't think those "Unsupported Features" apply.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.